# Is it possible to change the delimiter of AWS athena output file

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Here is my sample code where I create a file in S3 bucket using AWS Athena. The file by default is in csv format. Is there a way to change it to pipe delimiter ?

```py
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    client = boto3.client('athena')

    # Start Query Execution
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString="""
                    select * from srvgrp
                    where category_code = 'ACOMNCDU'
                    """,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': 'tmp_db'
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': 's3://tmp-results/athena/'
        }
    )
    queryId = response['QueryExecutionId']
    print('Query id is :' + str(queryId))
```

Comment: There does not appear to be an option for changing the format of files saved in the `OutputLocation`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do that with [CTAS query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html).

**BUT:**

- This is a hacky way and not what CTAS queries are supposed to be used for, since it will also create a new table definition in AWS Glue Data Catalog.
- I'm not sure about performance

```sql
CREATE TABLE "UNIQU_PREFIX__new_table"
WITH (
    format = 'TEXTFILE',
    external_location = 's3://tmp-results/athena/__SOMETHING_UNIQUE__',
    field_delimiter = '|',
    bucketed_by = ARRAY['__SOME_COLUMN__'],
    bucket_count = 1
) AS
SELECT *
FROM srvgrp
WHERE category_code = 'ACOMNCDU'
```

**Note:**

1. It is important to set `bucket_count = 1`, otherwise Athena will create multiple files.
2. Name of the table in `CREATE_TABLE ...` also should be unique, e.g. use timestamp prefix/suffix which you can inject during python runtime.
3. External location should be unique, e.g. use timestamp prefix/suffix which you can inject during python runtime. I would advise to embed table name into S3 path.
4. You need to include in `bucketed_by` only one of the columns from `SELECT`.
5. At some point you would need to clean up AWS Glue Data Catalog from all table defintions that were created in such way